# Asp.net core Web Api POST not working on 5.0 after upgrade

Tags: .net

I have a dotnet API project that I've upgrade from 2.2 to 5.0.

Since the upgrade, all my POST requests have stopped working (getting 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.') when the controller tries to do something with the POSTed model.

When I run in Debug mode then the model is null.

An example of an API - the debug shows that model is null, so the model.enteredDateFrom fails with an object reference error.

> ```
>     [HttpPost]
>     [Route("GetJobsReport")]
>     public async Task<IActionResult> GetJobsReport([FromBody] JobsReportSearchViewModel model)
>     {
>         if (model.enteredDateFrom != null)
> ```

I have an Angular front end which hasn't changed and I've confirmed I'm sending the right parameters - but it's happening on all POSTS.

I'm not even sure how to start troubleshooting this.

Answer (score 0):

If the model parameter in your GetJobsReport method is null, it means that the API is not able to deserialize the JSON object sent from the Angular frontend into the JobsReportSearchViewModel object. This could be due to a mismatch between the JSON object and the model, or due to an issue with the JSON serialization/deserialization process.

these suggestions may solve your problems :

Check that the JSON object sent from the Angular frontend matches the JobsReportSearchViewModel model. You can use browser developer tools to inspect the network traffic and check that the JSON payload is being sent correctly.

Check that the JSON payload is being sent with the correct content type. It should be application/json for JSON payloads.

Check that the JobsReportSearchViewModel model is correctly defined in your C# code. Ensure that all properties are present and have the correct data types.

Check that the JSON serializer is configured correctly in your API project. In ASP.NET 5, the default JSON serializer is System.Text.Json. Ensure that it is configured correctly in your API project and that any custom serialization settings are applied correctly.

If you are using custom JSON serialization/deserialization, ensure that it is working correctly and not causing any issues.

Check that any middleware or filters in your API project are not interfering with the JSON serialization/deserialization process.

Try adding [ApiController] attribute to the controller to enable automatic model validation.

Add ModelState.IsValid check to your controller method to ensure that the model is valid.

I hope you can solve your problem By following these steps.